# Module ip_tables not found after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, kernel, upgrade, kernel-modules

Since I upgraded recently my Ubuntu server from 20.04 to 22.04 I have an issue with Docker. Docker will not start any more after reboot, because of the `ip_tables` module.

After every reboot of Ubuntu the `ip_tables` module is not available, `lsmod | grep ip` returns only:

```
multipath              20480  0
```

And

```
$ sudo iptables -L
iptables/1.8.7 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported
```

After reinstalling the Linux kernel modules and activating `ip_tables` it works for the current boot. With the next reboot, the module will be unavailable again, and it has to be reinstalled and activated again to work for the current boot:

```
$ sudo apt reinstall linux-modules-$(uname -r)
[...]
Setting up linux-modules-5.15.0-41-generic (5.15.0-41.44) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-41-generic (5.15.0-41.44) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-122-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-122-generic
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
Scanning processes...
Scanning processor microcode...
Scanning linux images...

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
$ sudo modprobe ip_tables
```

After that, the `ip_tables` module can be found again with `lsmod`

```
$ lsmod | grep ip
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  7 xt_conntrack,nft_compat,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,xt_nat,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE
multipath              20480  0
```

And `sudo iptables -L` returns the IP-Table like expected (Docker works also again)…

Setting the update alternative for iptables to legacy, will just result in a different error:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
$ sudo iptables -L
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Does anyone have an idea what has been gone wrong, that I do need to reinstall the kernel modules after every reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem.

Following [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+bug/1962053/comments/21) solved the issue.

To know which kernel versions where available, I used.

```bash
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by:

```
apt-get install -y --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)-generic linux-image-$(uname -r)-generic
```

For some reason ip_tables.ko had disappeared from /lib/modules but by reinstalling kernel and modules brought them back. After this running:

```
modprobe ip_tables
```

worked ok.